# PHP 8 $_SERVER['SSL_PROTOCOL'] is missing on some servers, how to determine encryption protocl and version

Tags: php, php-8, tls1.3

We recently upgraded our servers to PHP 8 and on one of the servers the `$_SERVER['SSL_PROTOCOL']` variable is missing.

- I couldn't find any reference to it on php.net.
- I am aware that some variables are pulled from other parts of the system though I'm not familiar with where PHP gets this particular variable from.
- All search results I've found using quote operators revealed only irrelevant data.
- I attempted to see if the variable name was changed to something like `TLS_PROTOCOL` because SSL has been irrelevant for some time.

My goal is to ensure that clients are using TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 and this was the critical component to that. How do I either get `$_SERVER['SSL_PROTOCOL']` or at least determine the protocol and protocol version of the network encryption type being used by clients via PHP?

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but is that server serving https pages with Apache?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Not a stupid question, I should have mentioned Apache and yes.

Comment: "My goal is to ensure that clients are using TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3" can you not disable other protocols on the HTTP server?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, I've disabled 1.1 and older: https://www.immuniweb.com/ssl/jabcreations.com/2pIGVaRM/

Comment: Then no such clients will ever reach your PHP code.

Comment: @miken32 Please clarify...no one should be accessing server code.

Comment: I mean, what you’re trying to do is unnecessary because they will never connect.

Comment: @miken32 Oh, no I'm aware that people using IE6 from 2001 won't connect and frankly I do suspect that I'll be able to live with myself. ︀

Answer (score 1):

The SSL/TLS encryption is handled by your web server, not by PHP, so this variable has to be set there. The upgrade of PHP is coincidence - it's something else you've upgraded or re-built that has caused the difference.

If you are using Apache, this information is disabled for performance unless you set `SSLOptions +StdEnvVars`. See the documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html

A quick search suggests Nginx doesn't set this variable natively at all.

Comment: I know Apache handles it, I just didn't make the full connection after doing all of the searching, testing this out now...

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work; the documentation says that it'll work with `.htaccess` files and I've even outright rebooted the server a couple times for tests and nothing; e.g. `SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @John You say it's missing "on one of the servers"; presumably, there is some difference in the configuration of that server. Maybe something is specifically turning it _off_?

Comment: *sigh* It's a cPanel server so I'll call my host and check. Usually when it's something off like that it's cPanel... Will report back.